# NodeJs/Formidable, Uploading Images error

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, formidable

I am trying to make an Image/File upload form using NodeJs and Formidable. I'm not using express. Just formidable. But anyways, I tried the most common scripts with formidable, and none have worked.My code is basically exactly the same as the one from this tutorial: http://justinkjchang.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/image-uploader-using-node-js/
There are a lot of these tutorials around, and i've seen almost the exact same thing in some books, or videos, and they all seem to work, except mines. I have Installed formidable, and I have the latest version of both that, and Node. I'm on a mac too. When I try to upload, it'll go through the form.parse and everything, but when it tries to write the file, it throws this error:

```
/Users/USER/Documents/Node/requestHandlers.js:42
    fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png", function (error) {
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

I'm new to Nodejs, so any kind of help would be nice. I tried doing file.write too, and it still throws the same error. Any help would be gladly appreciated (:

Updated with code:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var qs = require("querystring"),
fs = require("fs"),
formidable = require("formidable"),
url = require( "url" );

function start(response, request) {
/*
var fileName = "start.html"
var localPath = __dirname;
var mimeType = "text/html";
var name = localPath + "/" + fileName;
getFile(name, response, mimeType);
console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
console.log("Serving File: " + name);
*/
var body = '<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" '+
    'content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body>'+
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" '+
    'method="post">'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple">'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload file" />'+
    '</form>'+
    '</body>'+
    '</html>';

console.log( "Request for 'start' is called." );

response.writeHead( 200, { "Content-Type" : "text/html" } );
response.end( body );
}

function upload(response, request) {
console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
console.log( "Preparing upload" );

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Dun Goofed");
    }
    console.log("parsing done");
    fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png", function (error) {
        if (error) {
            fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
            fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png");
        }
    });
    /* fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png", function(err){
        if(err){
            fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
            fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png");
        }
    }); */
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Received image: <br/>");
    response.write("<img src='./show' />");
    response.end(); 
});
}


exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
//exports.show = show;
```

I Omitted some parts because they have nothing to do with the file upload, please excuse the comments too, just old code. I also do not have a /show function because I erased it temporarily.
Also Here are the errors I get in the console. One of the errors is because the upload cancels. After I enter the file I want to upload, the browser just sits there for a while and waits for  request for the server, and in the console, it just stops before form.parse, and sits there doing nothing for about a minute, then it rolls out all the errors.

```
Web Server started on 127.0.0.1:8888
Request for / received.
About to route a request for /
Served a request for /
Request for 'start' is called.
Request for /upload received.
Received POST data chunk
About to route a request for /upload
Served a request for /upload
Request handler 'upload' was called.
Preparing upload
```

Successfully executes until here.
Then the browser waits for a while, and then It either pops up with no data received, or the webpage is unavailable, and then these errors come up in the console.

```
{}
[Error: Request aborted]
Dun Goofed
parsing done

/Users/USER/Documents/Node/requestHandlers.js:50
    fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png", function (error) {
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
at /Users/USER/Documents/Node/requestHandlers.js:50:31
at IncomingForm.<anonymous>    (/Users/USER/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:89:9)
at IncomingForm.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at IncomingForm._error (/Users/USER/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:272:8)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>     (/Users/USER/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:107:12)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at abortIncoming (http.js:1911:11)
at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1923:5)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Comment: is the name attribute of your html `file` - `upload` ? - `<file name="upload"` ?

Comment: Whoah, Sorry, I typed something different than I saw, My bad. Yes the Name Attribute is set to upload

Comment: hmm - so it is - `<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></form>` ? Might need to see the wider code if so

Comment: @RobSedgwick Yes it's that, I added the code to my question to so you can see it.

Comment: And i Changed Files.upload.path to files.files.path because I had seen somewhere that it might work, but it didn't. Problem is still the same

Comment: AFAIK - file.NAME refers to the `name` attribute of the file upload , - so it needs to be the same.

Just after the line `form.parse` can you add `console.log(files)` to have a look at that `files` object. Do you see anything relating to `path` and the key in which path is contained `files > SOMETHING > path ?

Comment: @RobSedgwick I added that, but it displays nothing, I also added the console errors too in the question.

Comment: Got the extra info - `Request aborted` is the problem . `Cannot read property 'path' of undefined` is a red herring. ( request was aborted so you are not creating any `file` object )

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

delete the code  `request.setEncoding("utf8");` in server.js

like this:

```
function start(route, handler) {
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        var postData = "";
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        route(handler, pathname, response, request);

    }).listen(8889);
}
```