# Formidable and Node.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: node.js, typeerror, formidable

If you're reading this, you're probably following Manuel Kiessling's Node tutorial. I was receiving the following error when completing the file upload part of the tutorial.

```
fs.rename(files.upload.path, "img/img.jpg", function(error) {
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

I searched around, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642232/formidable-upload-not-working-files-undefined-no-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733110/nodejs-formidable-uploading-images-error), but they were pretty inconclusive and provided little help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is true that the tutorial is passing request and response in the wrong order. The first thing I did is changed the order from `(response, request)` to `(request, response)`. (Make sure to do this everywhere). The reason for this is because I'm pretty sure the `onRequest` function in `HTTP`'s `createServer()` passes them in this order.

Once I did that, I still got the same error. But by logging the information coming through from my form

```
...
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
console.log("About to parse...");
form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {

    console.log("Parsing done.");
    console.dir(request.headers);
    console.log(fields);
    console.log(files);
...
```

I noticed that the `fields` key contained what I was looking for, and the `files` key was empty.

```
{ upload: '2015-03-08 14.54.06.jpg', 'Upload File': 'Submit' }
{}
```

From here it's clear that I could use `fields.upload`. Using this returned another error that it was not a string (or at least not one that formidable would accept). `toString()` didn't seem to work either, so I used the alternate conversion:

```
fs.rename(fields.upload + "", "img/img.jpg", function(error) {
    ...
}
```

Which is not ideal, but it did the trick.

This was done with `node@0.10.35` and `formidable@1.0.17`. I don't know if my solution will work for everyone, but hopefully it can point some of you in the right direction. The discrepancy is probably due to the fact that he used older versions of node and formidable in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue and struggled a lot only to finally find that I had made a typo.

What I had entered:

```
res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">');
```

What should have been:

```
res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
```

Notice the missing `-` in `form-data`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, with the same tutorial. Turns out I had a typo in the requestHandlers start() function that prints the HTML form. I had

```
'<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-date" ' +
```

when it should have been

```
'<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" ' +
```

(changed "date" to "data"). Fixing this one problem made it work for me.

So, take a very close look at the HTML form data in your requestHandlers start() function and see if there are any typos that are preventing the file upload from occuring correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, because the name of the input field was different as the fs.rename was trying to use.

Basically be sure that name in this line:

```
'<input type="file" name="UPLOADEDIMAGE">'+
```

Is same as this 2 lines:

```
fs.rename(files.UPLOADEDIMAGE.path, "/tmp/test.png", function(err) {

fs.rename(files.UPLOADEDIMAGE.path, "/tmp/test.png");
```