# Formidable file path undefined

Tags: javascript, formidable

I am having trouble with trying to rename my file to upload to the server, i have searched quite abit including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953535/formidable-and-node-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-path-of-undefined) but none seem to work for me. my code is working in another project so i copied over to this but it did not work out, all having the same error;path undefined

html:

```
<form action = "/assignment1/viewImage/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title"><br />
    <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
    <input type = "submit" value="Upload"/>
```

js(router):

```
handle["/assignment1/viewImage/upload"] = reqHandlers.reqUpload;
```

js(reqHandler):

```
function reqUpload(res, path, postData, req){
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.uploadDir = './tmp';
form.parse(req, function(err, field, file) {
    console.log("parsing done\n\n" + file.upload.path + "\n\n" + field);//file.upload.path and field is somehow undefined
    fs.rename(file.upload.path, "../images/test.png", function (err) {
        if (err) {
            fs.unlink("./tmp/test.png");
            fs.rename(file.upload.path, "../images/test.png");
        }

    });

    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write("Received image: <br/>");
    res.write("<img src='/assignment1/show' />");
    res.end();
});
}
```

console output:
[image: console output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late update; so i did copy it correctly except that i missed put the part on the server side(not shown) should not change the encoding to UTF-8(should be application/multiform), which caused the file path to be unable to be read by the program

Answer (score 1):

Try with a more recent version `npm i node-formidable/formidable#3.x`

Then use the `options.filename` instead of fs.rename

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 2022, Migration Issues.

```
function reqUpload(res, path, postData, req){

    const options = {
        uploadDir : './tmp'
    }

    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm(options);

    form.parse(req, function(err, field, file) {

        console.log("parsing done \n" + file.upload.filepath);
        console.log(file.upload.originalFilename, " ", file.upload.newFilename);
  
        res.end();
    });
}
```